# What is the best approach to process huge amount of data insertion efficiently

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm dealing with a HUGE amount of data entry. I need to know the best practice to insert/update table records after new entry inserted in another table.

By huge i mean we get more than 2 million rows a day, it's an ongoing process.

I tried creating a trigger that will insert or update the data depending on a complex logic.
But I doubt this is a good approach for doing this, I'm afraid it will be heavy on the database.

I use PostgreSQL 9.1

The current trigger looks like:

```
DECLARE
  AVar integer;
AdateVar timestamp without time zone;
AnameVar character varying(40);
BEGIN 
 SELECT id  INTO  AVar  FROM table1 WHERE ST_DWithin(NEW.position,ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitudedecimal,latitudedecimal ),4326) ,0.01447534783);
 select Adate INTO AdateVar from table2 where id = NEW. id  ORDER BY Adate DESC limit 1;
 IF (aVar > 0) THEN
   select name into AnameVar FROM table1 WHERE id = AVar;
     INSERT into table2 (id,name,date) SELECT  NEW.id,AnameVar,NEW.timestamp;
   ELSE
……….
 END IF;
RETURN NULL;
End;
```

**EDIT**

here is a piece of the trigger header and function, the function is too long. coz as i know the trigger cannot call more than one function! so it became very long and complicated, I posted just one case out of 12:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ts_trigger
  AFTER INSERT
  ON table1
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_trigger();
```

---

```
declare
Aposition geometry;
Cposition geometry;
Plong double precision;
Plat double precision;
Adate timestamp without time zone;
Cdate timestamp without time zone;
startDate timestamp without time zone;
CnotifDate timestamp without time zone;
AnotifDate timestamp without time zone;
lastmsg timestamp without time zone;
InsideCircle  integer;
InsideSquare  integer;
insidePoint  integer;
distance character varying(40);
-- this variables used to calculate the time in the table3
    inAction character varying(40);
    diff character varying(40);
    days character varying(40);
    hours character varying(40);
    str character varying(40);
    CinAction character varying(40);
    AinAction character varying(40);
BEGIN 


select time_stamp INTO Adate  from table1 where userid=NEW.userid and time_stamp < NEW.time_stamp order by time_stamp desc limit 1 ;
select  position INTO Aposition from table1 where userid=NEW.userid and time_stamp < NEW.time_stamp order by time_stamp desc limit 1;
select time_stamp INTO Cdate  from table1 where userid=NEW.userid and time_stamp > NEW.time_stamp order by time_stamp  limit 1; 
select position INTO Cposition from table1 where userid=NEW.userid and time_stamp > NEW.time_stamp order by time_stamp  limit 1;

SELECT p.num  INTO InsideCircle FROM table3 p WHERE ST_DWithin(Aposition,ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(p.longitudedecimal,p.latitudedecimal ), 4326) ,0.02171302174) ORDER BY ST_Distance(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(p.longitudedecimal,p.latitudedecimal ), 4326),Aposition) limit 1;
SELECT p.num  INTO InsideSquare FROM table3 p WHERE ST_DWithin(NEW.position ,ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(p.longitudedecimal,p.latitudedecimal ), 4326) ,0.02171302174) ORDER BY ST_Distance(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(p.longitudedecimal,p.latitudedecimal ), 4326),NEW.position) limit 1;
SELECT p.num  INTO insidePoint  FROM table3 p WHERE ST_DWithin(Cposition,ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(p.longitudedecimal,p.latitudedecimal ), 4326) ,0.02171302174) ORDER BY ST_Distance(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(p.longitudedecimal,p.latitudedecimal ), 4326),Cposition) limit 1;


-
    IF (InsideCircle >0 and (InsideCircle =InsideSquare or InsideSquare is null))THEN 
    select startDate INTO startDate  from myTable where id=NEW.userid and num = InsideCircle and startDate =Adate; 
        IF (InsideSquare >0)then 
            if (Cdate is not null )then 
                if (insidePoint is null)THEN 
                    diff = NEW.time_stamp  -startDate;
                    str= split_part(diff,' ',2);
                    IF(str = '')then
                    hours= split_part(diff,':',1);
                    days = '0';
                    ELSE
                    str= split_part(diff,' ',3);
                    IF(str = '') then
                    hours ='00';
                    days = split_part(diff,' ',1);
                    ELSE
                    hours= split_part( split_part(diff,' ',3),':',1);
                    days = split_part(diff,' ',1);
                    END IF;
                    END IF;
                    inAction = days || ',' ||hours;
                Update myTable SET notifDate = NEW.time_stamp , time_inAction=inAction WHERE id=NEW.userid  and num =InsideSquare ;
                END IF;

    END IF;
Return Null;
END;
```

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: postgreSQL, sorry forgot to mention it.

Comment: One observation: you never actually use Adatevar in the Insert

Comment: Is this a one-off data update or an ongoing process. And please define  HUGE (it means different things to different people).

Comment: If this is a bulk load: why not do it in plain SQL, instead of using this row-at-a-time processing method (which a trigger basically is)

Comment: @JohnBarça Thank you. by huge i mean we get more than 2 million rows a day, and yes, it's an ongoing process.

Comment: @wildplasser Would you please explain what you mean by plain SQL? Thanks

Comment: I don't know what fires the trigger, so lets assume it is table0 : *pseudocode* : `INSERT INTO table2 dst (a,b,c,...) select e,f,g FROM table1 xxx JOIN (select aaa, max(bbb) FROM table1 WHERE ...) zzz ON zzz.aaa = xxx.ddd;`

Comment: How often do you do the update branch, and how often the insert branch?  Does the 2 million new data arrive evenly throughout the day, or in chunks?  Are you sure that a fully ACID compliant database is really the best way to handle this?  I like PostgreSQL, but it is not always the right tool for the job.

Comment: It appears that the EDIT in the question changed an INSERT statement into a (rather simple) UPDATE to the *current* tuple (with some conditions) :: `Update myTable SET notifDate = NEW.time_stamp , time_inAction=inAction WHERE id=NEW.userid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for bulk updates/inserts, use batches. This will put less load on the database and will prevent WAL overload if its enabled.

Comment: I added details here dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75479/… I'd appreciate it if you could take a look.